# awk why the array stored is not retrieving in same order

Tags: awk

I have the following data

```
SB 1.2.27: SB 1.2.27
SB 1.2.28: SB 1.2.28, SB 1.2.29, SB 1.2.28-29
SB 1.2.29: SB 1.2.28, SB 1.2.29, SB 1.2.28-29
SB 1.2.30: SB 1.2.30
SB 1.3.1: SB 1.3.1
SB 1.21.1: SB 1.21.1
```

And i using the following script to extract the unique ones in the second column that too the only the `-` part

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=": "}{
    # I want only the dash part not the whole $2. eg: SB 1.2.28-29
    if(match($0,/(SB [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+)$/,hare)){
        sloka[$2] = hare[1]
    }else{
        sloka[$2]= $1
    }
}END{
    for (i in sloka){
        print sloka[i]": "i
    }
}' DATA.TXT
```

The result i am getting:

```
SB 1.2.28-29: SB 1.2.28, SB 1.2.29, SB 1.2.28-29
SB 1.2.30: SB 1.2.30
SB 1.2.27: SB 1.2.27
SB 1.3.1: SB 1.3.1
SB 1.21.1: SB 1.21.1
```

I am expecting:

```
SB 1.2.27: SB 1.2.27
SB 1.2.28-29: SB 1.2.28, SB 1.2.29, SB 1.2.28-29
SB 1.2.30: SB 1.2.30
SB 1.3.1: SB 1.3.1
SB 1.21.1: SB 1.21.1
```

and also not

```
SB 1.2.27: SB 1.2.27
SB 1.2.28-29: SB 1.2.28, SB 1.2.29, SB 1.2.28-29
SB 1.2.30: SB 1.2.30
SB 1.21.1: SB 1.21.1  (* this should be next)
SB 1.3.1: SB 1.3.1
```

Comment: in awk all arrays are in fact hashes. If you index them numerically it is possible to keep the order. If you index with strings, there's no such a thing as an order

Comment: ok. i didnt know, i will try with some index

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: Are you using GNU `awk`? Post `awk --version`

Comment: `GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My standard approach is to use a second, numerically indexed, array, like

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=": "; num_elms = 0;}{
    if not ($2 in sloka) {
        num_elms++
        lookup[num_elms] = $2
    }
    # I want only the dash part not the whole $2. eg: SB 1.2.28-29
    if(match($0,/(SB [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+)$/,hare)){
        sloka[$2] = hare[1]
    }else{
        sloka[$2]= $1
    }
}END{
    for (i = 1; i <= num_elms; i++){
        print sloka[lookup[i]]": "lookup[i]
    }
}' DATA.TXT
```

Note: I didn't test this, but it shows the pattern.

Comment: it will repeat the values with `-` . but now i can get unique values

Comment: I've changed the script a little. That might serve your needs now

Comment: awk built in fields, string positions, and array indices all start at 1, not 0, so you should do the same with user-defined arrays to avoid any confusion - you don't need `num_elms = 0;` as that's the default and then do `lookup[++num_elms] = $2` instead of `lookup[num_elms] = $2; num_elms++` and make the loop `for (i = 1; i <= num_elms; i++)`. The test `if (sloka[$2] == "")` should really be `if ($2 in sloka)`. You don't need the gawk-specific call to match() and the if-else, just do `sub(/-.*/,"")` or similar (I don't understand the logic there, just that you don't need match() for it!).

Comment: @Ed Morton I've added some of your suggestions. I don't think it should be regarded a flaw if variables are initialised. Furthermore, I personally don't like to increment indexes while assigning values to array cells. I don't save any work and incrementing after the assignment is easier to read (for me). I tried to preserve as much of the OP's original code as possible. That makes it easier for the OP to understand the changes.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for pointing that out. Fixed it. C programmers should stick to start counting from zero ;-)

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, I'd been programming in C for 10 years before trying to write awk - it was an adjustment :-)! The problem with starting arrays at 0 is you trip over awk starting them (and everything else!) at 1. As a trivial example you might write `arr[0]="foo"; arr[1]="bar"; arr[2]="etc"; ... END{for (i=0;i in arr;i++) print arr[i]}` and then realize you can simplify that first par to `split("foo bar etc",arr)` but then you just broke your END loop as it'll now print a blank line first. In larger awk scripts just trying to remember which arrays start at 0 vs 1 would be rough.

Comment: @Ronald: `if (sloka[$2] == "")` is changed to  `if ($2 in sloka)` in your edited answer.  So consider the first line where `$2=SB 1.2.27`. So `if ( "SB 1.2.27" in sloka)` will give false, so how will it store the count. I think it should check `if not  ($2 in sloka)`

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi you're absolutely right. `sloka[$2] == ""` tests if the entry is NOT there. I'll change it. Thank you for spotting this

Answer (score 2):

It's really not clear what you're trying to do - is this it?

```
$ awk -F'[:,] ' '!seen[$NF]++{sub(/[^:]+/,$NF); print}' file
SB 1.2.27: SB 1.2.27
SB 1.2.28-29: SB 1.2.28, SB 1.2.29, SB 1.2.28-29
SB 1.2.30: SB 1.2.30
SB 1.3.1: SB 1.3.1
SB 1.21.1: SB 1.21.1
```

Comment: Yes. Its correct now. `!seen[$NF]++` segregate base on last column value and then you replace.